# Remmina Remote DeskTop

Tags: remote, remmina

I have need to connect to office laptop behind firewall. I am able to connect to it using IOS and windows. But I am new to this tool. Here is the question. Where I have to mention remote PC name. If its server where I have to mention office domain..

Answer (score 0):

press  <kbd>Alt</kbd>   <kbd>F2</kbd>  open `Remmina Remote DeskTop` and click on `+`

fill entries here

```
Server = server:port
```

all options are easy to understand

[image]